# Get session value without page refresh php

Tags: php, ajax, class, session

I am working on app. Where I set some session value using ajax call. Later on without page changing I call another method where I use the session but it didn't work. I am calling both functions using ajax. First Ii call set method while after that I call get, but on get I didn't get the session value. What can cause be?

```
   public function getmysession()
   {
       if($_SESSION['mahmood']=='getit'){ echo "this is set session";}
   }


   public function setmysesion()
   {
       $_SESSION['mahmood'] = 'getit';
   }
```

Comment: are you sure you have `session_start();` in the top of you script?

Comment: yes i know session_start must for session use.But it works if page loads again.Not for me using ajax

Comment: your PHP script doesn't know if you are accessing it using AJAX or not, the behaviour should be the same in both cases. Please show more code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the session at the top of your script. So at the top of your file, put:

> [`session_start();`](https://www.php.net/session_start)

Comment: i am working on magento enviroment where i set and get session values without session_start().

Comment: You can't do that. Each file has to start the session, doesn't matter what environment you're in. The script also does not care if it's a page refresh or an ajax request.